# PHP setting up two output buffers with different contents in while loop

Tags: php, ob-get-contents

I have a Wordpress site and I am trying to loop over my posts in an AJAX call and I would like to store the HTML for the first post in the loop in a separate variable than the rest of the posts. How would I go about setting up the output buffer

```
if (have_posts()) :
  $i = 0;while(have_posts()): the_post();
    if ($i == 0):
      ob_start();
      get_template_part('templates/latest-post', get_post_format());
      $recent_post = ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean();
    else:
      ob_start();
      get_template_part('templates/remaining-posts', get_post_format());
      $remaining_posts = ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean();
    endif;
  $i++; endwhile;
endif;
```

This isn't working because the `ob_start` and `ob_clean` is being called on every iteration so I end up with only 1 post in the `$remaining_posts` variable, but I'm not sure how to set it up correctly.

Comment: Can you just concatenate? `$remaining_posts .= ob_get_contents()`. Probably also initialize `$remaining_posts` to an empty string before the loop, too.

Comment: @ChrisHaas that worked swimmingly! Thank you for the suggestion. If you would like to add it as an answer I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just concatenate that content using `.=`:

```php
// Initialize the remaining posts variable
$remaining_posts = '';

if (have_posts()) :
  $i = 0;while(have_posts()): the_post();
    if ($i == 0):
      ob_start();
      get_template_part('templates/latest-post', get_post_format());
      $recent_post = ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean();
    else:
      ob_start();
      get_template_part('templates/remaining-posts', get_post_format());

      // Concatenate
      $remaining_posts .= ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean();
    endif;
  $i++; endwhile;
endif;
```